# Is asking HR department about self-organised interest group a sufficient reason to warrant a drug test?

Tags: united-kingdom, employment, workplace

Using a throwaway account as I do not want to get into trouble.

### Background to cannabis

- Medical cannabis is legal in the UK since 2018
- 63% of Londoners supports legalisation for adult recreational use: https://www.standard.co.uk/news/uk/the-cannabis-debate-63-per-cent-of-londoners-think-uk-should-follow-canada-and-make-cannabis-legal-a4179291.html
- Major of London calls for evidence-based approach: https://www.standard.co.uk/news/london/sadiq-khan-time-for-cannabis-rethink-to-cut-violent-crime-a4276306.html

### Absolute rule at work

My workplace has an absolute rule:

> **WE NEVER** work under the influence of alcohol or drugs

- Fair game.
- Understood.
- Clear boundary.
- No ambiguity.

My understanding is that having absolute rule for work removes any liability for drug use outside of work?

### UK  law about drug testing

https://www.gov.uk/monitoring-work-workers-rights/drug-testing

> Workers can’t be made to take a drugs test but if they refuse when the employer has good grounds for testing, they may face disciplinary action.

In other words, if I want to keep my job I'll have to comply with the request. At the same time:

> Not single out particular employees for testing unless this is justified by the nature of their jobs.

Nature of job requires a lot of creativity.

### Negative influence VS positive influence?

One could argue that use of drugs is increasing my productive output.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychedelics_in_problem-solving_experiment

I'm not expecting a typical HR person to understand all the science behind it though.

### Communication at work

At work we communicate via various online tools, including Slack and Workplace by FB.

I've asked customer representatives from Slack and FB and they advised me to speak with HR.

**I'd like to ask my HR whether I can create cannabis advocacy group.**

My employer operates in 25+ countries, including those where cannabis is legal.

The "absolute rule" remains valid across all the jurisdictions.

Drug testing laws vary from country to country.

### Personal opinion

I think that I should keep cannabis away from work, I just hate all the social interactions with free alcohol at various company events...

In face-to-face conversations I'm always very friendly, polite, professional. Company is pushing agenda of LGBTQ+ gender diversity and equality, people are wearing the ️‍ lanyards. I'm aware of various legal issues: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGBT_rights_by_country_or_territory

I speak with them that what is legal or illegal remains largely arbitrary and I'm supporting facts, research, data, science.

### Question

1. I ask "can I organise a group"
2. They say "we a want drug test"
3. I say on what grounds?

**Do I have grounds to ask on what grounds?**

[gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/monitoring-work-workers-rights/drug-testing) resource once again:

> Workers can’t be made to take a drugs test but if they refuse when the employer has good grounds for testing, they may face disciplinary action.

Comment: Huge amounts of irrelevant commentary, formatting all over the place, no connection between the question and any of the previous sections. Please fix the question - evidently you understand enough of Stack Exchange to know what should and shouldn't be in it.

Comment: You can simply **SKIP** all the "background information" and focus on the question - is asking HR for permission to organize an interest group offline a sufficient ground to request the drug test?

Answer (score 1):

> Do I have grounds to ask on what grounds?

Yes, although the issue of whether "*employee has grounds*" in and of itself has no relevance from a legal standpoint.

For instance, the employee might sense or believe that he is being *unjustifiably* singled out for drug tests. Thus he has *grounds* --even if only subjective ones-- to inquire of the employer what prompted the request for drug tests. However, the excerpt you reproduce nowhere indicates that the employer has an obligation to address the employee's inquiry.

> Is asking HR department about self-organised interest group a sufficient reason to warrant a drug test?

Perhaps, and most often also that is highly subjective.

Where "interest group" refers to a cannabis advocacy group, it is reasonable for the employer to conjecture that the employee is using drugs. That is because usually a person who is not into drugs is not into supporting them either. This means "*the employer has good grounds for testing*", especially if workplace policy aims to avoid any and all negative impact of alcohol or drugs.